# How to fetch value from multiple table through pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I'm trying to fetch value from different tables. I get the value but it repeat same quantity. I'm getting this [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFSRW.png)
I expect this [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U8Kw.png)
Here is my **controller code**

```php
$orders = Order::all();
view('admin.order.index', compact('orders'));
```

Here is my **model relationship**

```php
       return $this->belongsToMany(FoodItem::class, 'order_food_items', 'order_id', 'food_item_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function orderItems() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderFoodItem::class);
    }
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Here is in **blade code**, May be I'm doing wrong

```php
@foreach ($orders as $key => $order)
    @foreach ($order->orderFoodItems as $product)
        @foreach ($order->orderFoodItemPrice as $price)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $key + 1 }}</th>
                <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{ asset('/storage/items/food/' . $product->image) }}"
                        alt="">
                </td>
                <td>{{ $order->user->name }}</td>
                <td>
               <span class="badge badge-primary">Pending</span></td>
                <td>something</td>
                <td>{{ $price->discounted_price }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you want answers, please include the expected result and the actual result you are getting. It might also be helpful to know the table structure, but in this case it doesn't seem important to me. BTW, is there a reason why you are explicitly specifying the foreign key names for order and food item? Also, if you stick to the Laravel naming conventions and rename the pivot table to order_food_item (or food_item_order for that matter), you can also even get rid of the second parameter.

Comment: It looks like your relations are wrong? shouldn't OrderFoodItemPrice be related to OrderFoodItem instead of Order??

Comment: I updated my relations. check the post again,. Now, only problem is when I add same product into order table, then the quantity of that item is not shown properly. see the image